# ArrayBuffer - размер "элемента"

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста насчет ArrayBuffer, что то я не могу понять:

```
let my_buff = new ArrayBuffer(1); 
alert(my_buff .byteLength)
my_buff [0] = 1000; 
alert(my_buff [0]);
```

alert - выводит на экран - значение 1000. Я не могу понять, как это ?

Правильно ли я понимаю, что ArrayBuffer - это что то типа void или массива char в С/С++ ?
Если да, и если один "элемент" в ArrayBuffer занимает 1 байт, а byteLength выводит размер == 1, то как числовое значение 1000 поместилось в 1 байт ??

Разве не должно произойти переполнение и при выводе - вывестись другое число ?

Comment: что за переменная `buffer.byteLength`?

Comment: @Grundy, опечатка - поправил.

Comment: ArrayBuffer это не массив, и когда ты делаешь присваивание `my_buff [0] = 1000;` ты просто в объект добавляешь поле `0` со значение 1000 - это никак не влияет на то, что хранится в `ArrayBuffer`

Comment: @Grundy, а можете немного пояснить, что значит "в объект добавляешь поле 0 со значение 1000" ? Что за объект ? Когда мы создаем массив - под него выделяется оперативная память, "значение" добавляется в эту память. Если я выделил 1 байт - то каким образом в этот 1 байт - поместилось значение 1000 ?

Comment: сейчас делаешь то же самое что и `var a = { length: 0}; a[0] = 1000;` и ожидаешь, что у тебя поменяется `length`

Comment: @Grundy, так, а размер "var" - какой ? явно больше 1 байт и вообще он динамический какой то.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138264/discussion-between-grundy-and-staxcelrom).

Comment: Для размышлений: `my_buff['abcd'] = 'efghijkl';`